# Coherently Organizing Charges on an Invoice Report

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a terrible invoicing report that breaks surcharges down just like this:

[image: Current Report Format]

My desired output (open to suggestions if there's something more intelligent) is one where I can see the transaction number, its reference number, and all the types of charges associated with it, like so:

[image: Desired Output]

Can someone assist with either a helper column or macro or Get-And-Transform, etc. ?

Comment: Hi @user1213489 welcome to Super User,,, what u have tried is one way and it can be improved,,, another is a separate INVOICE for each item,, so [edit] your post & be clear and loud all about your need,, also share the formula if any U have used for current OUTPUT !

Comment: **Continue** the most easiest is COPY along with Headers & Paste with Transpose,,, you get  good looking results in COLUMNS ☺

Answer (score 0):

Here is a `Power Query` solution:

- `Data--> Get & Transform --> From Table/Range`
- Paste the M-Code below into the `Advanced Editor`
- In Line2, change the name of the Table to reflect your actual table name for your data
- If you hover over the entries in the Applied Steps window, and/or double click on the Gear icons, you will get an idea of what is going on.

**Algorithm**

- Create "Label" columns for the `EN, Tax, and Total` columns to make format consistent with the code type columns
- Unpivot all but the first two columns to create a vertical array
- Add a column for the `Charge Amount` so it is on the same row as the `Charge Type`
- Filter out the unwanted rows and remove the unneeded columns

**M Code**

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table6"]}[Content],
    
    //create label columns for EN, Tax and Total
    addEN = Table.AddColumn(Source, "EN Label", each "EN"),
    addTax = Table.AddColumn(addEN, "Tax Label", each "Tax"),
    addTotal = Table.AddColumn(addTax, "Total Label", each "Total"),

    //Reorder the columns
    reOrder = Table.ReorderColumns(addTotal,
                List.Combine({List.RemoveLastN(Table.ColumnNames(Source),3),  
                            List.Combine(List.Zip(
                                {List.LastN(Table.ColumnNames(addTotal),3),
                                List.LastN(Table.ColumnNames(Source),3)
                            }))
                        })
    ),

    //replace nulls with blanks so we don't lose them during unpivot
    blankIt = Table.ReplaceValue(reOrder,null,"",Replacer.ReplaceValue,Table.ColumnNames(reOrder)),

    //Unpivot other than first two columns
    #"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(blankIt, {"Transaction", "Reference"}, "Attribute", "Charge Type"),

    //Move Amount to same row as the Service Code
    #"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Unpivoted Other Columns", "Index", 0, 1, Int64.Type),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Index", "Charge Amount", each if [Charge Type] = "" then null 
else if Number.Mod([Index],2) = 0 then 
    #"Added Index"[Charge Type]{[Index]+1}
    else null),

    //filter out unneeded rows
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Added Custom", each ([Charge Amount] <> null)),

    //remove unneeded columns
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Filtered Rows",{"Attribute", "Index"}),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Removed Columns",{{"Transaction", type text}, {"Reference", type text}, {"Charge Type", type text}, {"Charge Amount", Currency.Type}})
in
    #"Changed Type"
```

**Original Data**

[image]s

**Results**

[image]

***NOTE:** With a little modification, you can add a blank row between each Transaction group*

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table6"]}[Content],
    //create label columns for EN, Tax and Total
    addEN = Table.AddColumn(Source, "EN Label", each "EN"),
    addTax = Table.AddColumn(addEN, "Tax Label", each "Tax"),
    addTotal = Table.AddColumn(addTax, "Total Label", each "Total"),

    //Reorder the columns
    reOrder = Table.ReorderColumns(addTotal,
                List.Combine({List.RemoveLastN(Table.ColumnNames(Source),3),  
                            List.Combine(List.Zip(
                                {List.LastN(Table.ColumnNames(addTotal),3),
                                List.LastN(Table.ColumnNames(Source),3)
                            }))
                        })
    ),

    //replace nulls with blanks so we don't lose them during unpivot
    blankIt = Table.ReplaceValue(reOrder,null,"",Replacer.ReplaceValue,Table.ColumnNames(reOrder)),

    //Unpivot other than first two columns
    #"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(blankIt, {"Transaction", "Reference"}, "Attribute", "Charge Type"),

    //Move Amount to same row as the Service Code
    #"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Unpivoted Other Columns", "Index", 0, 1, Int64.Type),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Index", "Charge Amount", each if [Charge Type] = "" then null 
else if Number.Mod([Index],2) = 0 then 
    #"Added Index"[Charge Type]{[Index]+1}
    else null),
    //filter out unneeded rows
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Added Custom", each ([Charge Amount] <> null)),

    //remove unneeded columns
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Filtered Rows",{"Attribute", "Index"}),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Removed Columns", {"Transaction"}, {{"Grouped", each _, type table [Transaction=nullable text, Reference=nullable text, Charge Type=nullable text, Charge Amount=nullable number]}}),
    #"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "addBlankRow", each Table.InsertRows([Grouped],
  Table.RowCount([Grouped]), 
    {Record.FromList(
       List.Repeat({null}, Table.ColumnCount(#"Removed Columns")),
       Table.ColumnNames(#"Removed Columns"))})),
    #"Removed Columns1" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom1",{"Transaction", "Grouped"}),
    #"Expanded addBlankRow" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Removed Columns1", "addBlankRow", {"Transaction", "Reference", "Charge Type", "Charge Amount"}, {"Transaction", "Reference", "Charge Type", "Charge Amount"}),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Expanded addBlankRow",{{"Transaction", type text}, {"Reference", type text}, {"Charge Type", type text}, {"Charge Amount", Currency.Type}}),
    #"Removed Bottom Rows" = Table.RemoveLastN(#"Changed Type",1)
in
    #"Removed Bottom Rows"
```

[image]